# styled component how to pass width props to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, css-in-js

I'm new in styled components . I want to set input width by passing props to component. 
Expected output should be :

```
<Input width=30px> or <Input width=100%>
```

Here is my component:

```
import styled from "styled-components"

const UIInput = styled.input`
  padding: 5px;
  width: ${props => props.width ? width : 'auto'}
`

export default UIInput
```

Answer (score 5):

In this little snippet: `${props => props.width ? width : 'auto'}`, you forget that `width` is on the `props`-object. To fix it:

```
${props => props.width ? props.width : 'auto'}
```

You can see my working example below:

```js
const UIInput = styled.input`
  padding: 5px;
  width: ${props => props.width ? props.width : 'auto'}
`

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <div>
      <p>300px</p>
      <UIInput width="300px" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>80%</p>
      <UIInput width="80%"/>
    </div>
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/styled-components/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: What about just:
${props => props.width || 'auto'}

Comment: @FabioEspinosa certainly an option, I just fixed OP's code. I actually think the new null coalescing operator would be even better: `${props => props.width ?? 'auto'}`. Right now if `props.width` is falsy (e.g. `0`) it would default to `auto`, and maybe you want that 0?